# Мultiline text in Pug

Tags: pug

I need to paste in my .pug file a php code which won’t compile just for reading as common text. Proceed it with l for every line . Please advice if any other way to do it
header.header

```
.header-wrapper.wrapper

    .header-inner.inner

        |   <?
        |        $friends = 10;
        |        switch($friends):
        |            case 0:
        |                echo "<p>you have no friends</p>";
        |            break;
        |            case 1:
        |                echo "<p>you have a friend</p>";
        |            break;
        |            default:
        |                echo "<p>you have a ${friends} friends</p>";
        |        endswitch;
        |    ?>
```

Comment: Welcome! Please read guidelines on how to ask a good question! -> https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `.` after a tag to add a [block of plain text](https://pugjs.org/language/plain-text.html#block-in-a-tag) without relying on pipes.

If you want to write PHP code that renders as text for reading, it's probably best to do so in a [`<pre>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/pre) for semantics and readability.

```
.header-wrapper.wrapper
  .header-inner.inner
    pre.
      <?
        $friends = 10;
        switch($friends):
          case 0:
            echo "<p>you have no friends</p>";
            break;
          case 1:
            echo "<p>you have a friend</p>";
            break;
          default:
            echo "<p>you have ${friends} friends</p>";
        endswitch;
      ?>
```